# individual targets for a cmake conversion of multiple projects

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, target

We are trying to convert an old buildsystem to use cmake. The directory structure currently looks like this.

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
dir5
dir6
```

For information we have around 70 directories, each of those outputting an RPM package.

Each of these folders are currently using hand written Makefiles to do the following (broadly speaking):

1. compile code
2. create rpm from the compilation results

Our main problem is that there are some dependencies, mainly library dependencies, between directories, let's say dir1 depends on dir3. That means that some dir3 targets should be compiled before some targets from dir1 are compiled. This is currently done in a hackish manner ( cd ../dir3 && make that_lib ).

We know that with cmake we can have all dependencies resolved by just having a "root" CMakeLists.txt that does something like:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(dir1)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(dir2)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(dir3)
...
```

Questions:

1. how can we keep the current way of working that offers to the developer the possibility to compile a single rpm but using cmake?
2. Or to put it differently: can we compile just one directory from the directory list?
3. Is there a way to pass a directory name (or something similar) as target to the cmake generated makefiles and that should build what is inside that directory taking into account the dependencies?

Thanks!

Comment: CMake is usually very good at keeping track of dependencies, as long as you remember to mention them for CMake.

Comment: In order to migrate to cmake you have to stop thinking about "directories" and start thinking about "targets".  Pretend your entire build environment lived in a single directory, and create individual targets built out of the various files.  Then, other targets would be defined to depend on the first targets.  Etc.  It's irrelevant to cmake (and really, to any well-constructed build system) what directories things live in.  It's not really the case that `dir1` depends on `dir3`: instead, some target built in `dir1` depends on a target built in `dir3`.  That's what you have to capture.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean I should simply do a make and most likely it will be fast, even though we have almost 70 directories? (I've updated the question)

Comment: @MadScientist I have some cmake experience but I don't know all the internals of it and that's why I am asking for an opinion here. It would've been great to start the project from scratch but that's not the case.

Comment: You don't have any cmake files, you're converting, right?  So you ARE starting from scratch (writing a build system from scratch).  Be clear, I never suggested you ACTUALLY change your setup to be all in one directory.  I said PRETEND it's all in one directory.  You shouldn't change any locations of any files, but to write cmake you need to stop thinking about "building a directory" and start thinking about "building a target (which might happen to live in a directory)".  cmake defines relationships between TARGETS, not directories.

Comment: Just to be clear, it would have been far better for your makefile environment to have been written in terms of targets, not directories, as well.  But make allows you do get away with stuff like that; cmake won't, not really.

Answer (score 0):

1. In each directory you have a self-contained* CMakeLists.txt file which you can use to build the target and create an RPM.
2. Since each directory has its own CMakeLists.txt with its own target(s) you can choose whatever target you want to build and leave the rest unbuilt. If a target depends on another target then it will build all the dependencies first.
3. See 2.

(*) By "self-contained" I mean non-dependant on the top CMake file. It should still be able to be built by including it with `add_directory()` from the top.